# Disable "fill" attribute when using Styled CSS

Tags: highcharts

I am using the latest version of highstock.js (v5.0.14) and my custom styles (using CSS) are being usurped by inline fill attributes.

For example, this CSS:

```
.highcharts-color-0 {
    fill: #2b908f;
    stroke: #2b908f;
}
```

Is being overwritten by this HTML attribute:

```
<path fill="rgba(124,181,236,0.75)" ... />
```

I am looking to disable the fill attribute. Using !important does not work.

This problem came after I upgraded to v5.0.14 (previously using v5.0.9 where the "fill" attribute was not in use)

Comment: If you want to change color of the line in line chart you need to modify `.highcharts-graph` class too. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/su4nnx41/. Also, could you provide me with a demo where this occurs?

Comment: No effect, when using v5.0.9 the fill="" attribute did not exist. With v5.0.14 the fill="" attribute exists, and it overrides anything I set in CSS.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

A more effective and durable way to change the default colors Highstock uses is  by calling the function `Highcharts.setOptions()` (see http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Highcharts.setOptions) and defining the colors there.

For example, you could do define your own colors as follows:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: [ 
        'blue',    /* first color chosen */
        'red',     /* second color chosen */
        '#2b908f'  /* third color chosen */
    ]
});
```

In this code, `colors` is an array of values.

Highstock will cycle through this array and use them for each series that is drawn on the chart. Using this example, the first series will plot with a fill color of blue, the second with red, and the third with the hex value #2b908f.

Place this code **before** you define your chart options so that it will inherit what you set.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I really don't want to use HTML/SVG styling in this way. I've got everything else setup to use CSS, it is the fill attribute that is causing problems; I need to some how remove it from being generated (as was the case in v5.0.9)

Comment: You can get rid of a specific attribute (for example fill) by using jQuery attr() function. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cfprrywb/.